# JPA / Hibernare do not insert / update in Child table if migrating from BMP to CMP

Tags: hibernate, jpa, ejb-3.0

I am upgrading the Java Project from Bean Managed Persistence (BMP) to JPA / Hibernate. In my legacy project there is a separate database calls for all child entities. In JPA / Hobernate, i have oneToMany relationship and it tries to insert the child table also.

In JPA / Hibernate, is there any way to control and do not update / create a child table?